# 1C 8.3. В конфигурации в разделе Обработки выходят не те реквизиты

Tags: 1с

1C 8.3. В конфигурации в разделе Обработки выходят не те реквизиты при выборе данных.

Скриншот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. если создам новый реквизит, то в данных его не смогу найти (и выбрать), т.к. там совершенно другие реквизиты.

Как найти реквизиты, где они находятся?

*P.S. создал галочку, но не смогу привязать реквизит, чтобы можно было прикреплять из текущего объекта*

Comment: Чего вы хотите сделать? Ни черта непонятно из вопроса. Выбрать реквизиты куда?

Comment: @Sagittarius
Сложно объяснить. Если в двух словах, мне нужно в форме Обработка добавить галочку (флажок), который при сохранении запоминает своё значение (Истина/Ложь). В форме объекта документов было достаточно перетащить флажок и прикрепить вновь созданный реквизит (выбираешь в разделе данные) и в 1С:Предприятии я без проблем сохранял положение флажка (Истина/Ложь). А в форме раздела Обработка (конкретно: АРМграфик) я не смогу выбрать вновь созданный реквизит, т.к. его в списке нет (Там какие-то другие реквизиты, в скринште показал)

Comment: Покажите саму форму. Объясните, что за флажок и за что он отвечает. И нет такого "... в форме Обработка...", есть форма объекта, а объекты бывают разные. В данном случае это форма обработки.

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание что реквизиты бывают *двух видов*. Реквизиты Объекта (Справочник, Документ, Обработка) и Реквизиты Формы этого объекта.

Реквизиты Объекта - можно посмотреть открыв/развернув объект в списке объектов конфигурации;

Реквизиты Формы - можно посмотреть открыв соответствующую Форму;